# Maximum in solution set to a Diophantine equation related to unit fractions

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, unit-fractions

Some time ago, Kellogg communicated to Carmichael a result with an incomplete proof, which was soon after verified as correct. I do not recall the source but recall the result. Define

$$S_n = \{ (x_1,x_2 \dots x_n) \subset \mathbb{N}^n: \sum x_i^{-1} = 1\}.$$

And regard elements of $S_n$ identical up to a permutation as the same element. I am interested in the question:

> For each $n$, what is the largest integer $l(n)$ such that it appears as a member of some element of $S_n$?

Define the sequence  $u_n$ with $u_1 = 1$ and $u_i = u_{i-1}(u_{i-1}+1).$ Then Kellogg reasoned that $l(n)$ is bounded above by $u_n$.

**The question of this post:** As this was a very old result, has there since arisen a better description of $l(n)$? Exact values for certain arguments, lower bounds, sharper upper bounds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$1={1\over2}+{1\over2}={1\over2}+{1\over3}+{1\over6}={1\over2}+{1\over3}+{1\over7}+{1\over42}={1\over2}+{1\over3}+{1\over7}+{1\over43}+{1\over1806}=\cdots$$ so certainly the sequence $u_n$, which is $1,2,6,42,1806,\dots$, is a lower bound as well for $l(n)$.

$u_n$ is [tabulated](http://oeis.org/A007018) at the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences.

A proof is attributed to D. R. Curtiss, On Kellogg's Diophantine problem, Amer. Math. Monthly 29 (1922), pp. 380-387.

Also, the OEIS entry says,

Using the methods of Aho and Sloane, Fibonacci Quarterly 11 (1973), 429-437, it is easy to show that $a(n)$ is the integer just a tiny bit below the real number $\theta^{2^n}-1/2$, where $\theta \approx 1.597910218$ is the exponential of the rapidly convergent series $\sum_{n\ge0} \log(1+1/a_n)/2^{n+1}$. For example, $\theta^{32} - 1/2 \approx 3263442.0000000383$.

Others who have written on this problem are
Tanzo Takenouchi, On an indeterminate equation, Proc. Phys.-Math. Soc. Japan(3), 3(1921) 78-92.
David Eppstein, Ten algorithms for Egyptian fractions, Mathematica. in Education and Research, 4(1995) 5-15. This article is also available on the web at http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/numth/egypt/intro.html – see also https://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/numth/egypt/curtiss.html
O. T. Izhboldin & L. D. Kurlyandchik, Unit fractions, Proc. St. Petersburg Math. Soc., 111(1995) 193-200; MR 99m:ll024.